# evaluating a user-defined regex from STDIN in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to make an on-the-fly pattern tester in Perl.
Basically it asks you to enter the pattern, and then gives you a >>>> prompt where you enter possible matches. If it matches it says "%%%% before matched part  after match" and if not it says "%%%! string that didn't match". It's trivial to do like this:

```
while(<>){
    chomp;
    if(/$pattern/){
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

but I want to be able to enter the pattern like `/sometext/i` rather than just `sometext`
I think I'd use an eval block for this? How would I do such a thing?

Comment: Perhaps you should just use Devel::REPL instead of writing your own.

Comment: it's to learn Perl, not for a project

Comment: I'm confused: for the purpose of the exercise, why _can't_ you simply use `/$pattern/i`? Having said that, don't forget that you can always attack the problem the other way: change the string you're testing (make it all upper or all lower) rather than changing the match. This is often useful when handling simple user-input (to catch typos): Q or q, QuiT, quIt, etc.

Comment: I was building off of the exercise I had--it's not that I wanted it to match any case *all the time*, but I wanted to be able to specify the whole regex from input. It was my own exercise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a job for string [eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html), just remember not to eval untrusted strings.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $regex = <>;
$regex = eval "qr$regex" or die $@;
while (<>) {
    print  /$regex/ ? "matched" : "didn't match", "\n";
}
```

Here is an example run:

```
perl x.pl
/foo/i
foo
matched
Foo
matched
bar
didn't match
^C
```

Comment: You mean if the user passes in the string "s/foo/bar/"?  In that case I would say something like `my $subst = <>; while (<>) { eval $subst or die $@; print }`, but again, this is __very__ dangerous.  Whatever the user passes in on the first line will be executed as Perl code.

Comment: I did try something similar - but the patter in the substitution kept failing to match anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can write `/(?i:<pattern>)/` instead of `/<pattern>/i`.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
my $foo = "My bonnie lies over the ocean";

print "Enter a pattern:\n";
while (<STDIN>) {
   my $pattern = $_;
   if (not ($pattern =~ /^\/.*\/[a-z]?$/)) {
      print "Invalid pattern\n";
   } else {
      my $x = eval "if (\$foo =~ $pattern) { return 1; } else { return 0; }";
      if ($x == 1) {
         print "Pattern match\n";
      } else {
         print "Not a pattern match\n";
      }
   }
   print "Enter a pattern:\n"
}
```